# Is img.onload definitely required for drawimage? And how many times is it required?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas3').getContext("2d");
var img=new Image();
img.src="images/sprite1.png";
img.onload=function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,160,260,0,0,400,300);
}
```

Do I need to call the onload every time I want to redraw the image? Must the drawimage be "within" the onload function? What goes in the onload function? When I put the drawimage outside of the onload function, the image does not appear. What's the normal approach if I were to animate my sprite? Does the onload function run throughout the whole game? I've look through a few tutorials and figured that all of them work differently and I wish to know the most basic form of how this works.

Comment: You typically combine all sprites into a single image so that you only have to load one image.

Comment: I know what a sprite sheet is, but my problem is that, I want to know if the onload function is required to draw image, as when I put the drawimage outside of the onload function, it does not work, even if I put a flag within the onload function and draw and check for the flag it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not required. It's only required that the image exists when you use that function, and onload is the way to guarantee this if your loading the images dynamically.

Comment: so why doesn't it work when the drawimage were put outside of the function itself? likevar ctx = document.getElementById('canvas3').getContext("2d");
    var img=new Image();
    img.src="images/sprite1.png";
    img.onload=function(){

       
    } ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,160,260,0,0,400,300);

Comment: Because the image is not loaded yet. Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: Ohh I figure out the reason why when I put the drawimage outside it doesn't work, it's because that I didn't put any comment to call that function I suppose, it worked after I put the drawimage in the init function and called it using   window.addEventListener('load', init, false); then it worked. Am I understanding this concept correctly?